# Sheets Script to copy parts of a row based on Cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

So. This should be simple And I can do what I need with (=QUERY(MAIN!A:H, "select A,C,F where H='OPEN'") But I can not sort or edit. So I am trying to make a script that copys over from the "MAIN" tab to the "OPEN" tab Just Column A,C or F when column H is changed to OPEN. I need to put it on a trigger so that the information stays on the open tab and I can edit and sort it. The problem is. I am not great at Scripts and I can not figure out how to do just Column A, C and F. I have so far.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11PfKqDhQnBkDM9qIw3CjVUa9-fOTTVg51TzWzHXUo5w/edit?usp=sharing

```
  function CopyDataToNewFile() {
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11PfKqDhQnBkDM9qIw3CjVUa9-fOTTVg51TzWzHXUo5w').getSheetByName('MAIN'),
    sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(4, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(),
    targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11PfKqDhQnBkDM9qIw3CjVUa9-fOTTVg51TzWzHXUo5w').getSheetByName('OPEN');
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
sourceSheet.getRange(6, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn())
```

}

Comment: Do you mind sharing a redacted version of the sheet? Trying to understanding the data schema of the sheet (i.e. if it has only 1 row or multiple rows would be added there & so on).

Comment: Is the script bound to the spreadsheet ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11PfKqDhQnBkDM9qIw3CjVUa9-fOTTVg51TzWzHXUo5w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT:

If you don't want the script to run automatically when the Status column from MAIN is edited, use this function instead:

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MAIN');
  var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('OPEN');
  targetSheet.clear();
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i][7] == 'OPEN') {
      var dataA = values[i][0];
      var dataC = values[i][2];
      var dataF = values[i][5];
      targetSheet.appendRow([dataA, dataC, dataF]);    
    }
  }
}
```

=========================================

If you want the script to run every time column H is edited, use this below. The script does nothing if the edited cell is from column H from MAIN, so don't worry about an edit in OPEN changing the data from MAIN.

All data is copied to the first 3 columns of the OPEN tab. Also, all previous data in OPEN tab is deleted before getting copied:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet_name = sourceSheet.getName();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  if(sheet_name == 'MAIN' && column == 8) {
    var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    CopyDataToNewFile(values);
  }
}

function CopyDataToNewFile(values) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('OPEN');
  targetSheet.clear(); // This clears previous data in OPEN tab, delete this line if you don't want this to happen.
  // Looping through each row in MAIN tab
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    // Checking if column H value is 'OPEN'
    if(values[i][7] == 'OPEN') {
      // Getting values from A, C, F columns
      var dataA = values[i][0];
      var dataC = values[i][2];
      var dataF = values[i][5];
      targetSheet.appendRow([dataA, dataC, dataF]);    
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted to do, and I'm sorry if I misunderstood your purpose.

Comment: I am getting a line 15 error  (for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {   )  Also I need to set this up to run on a trigger. So I can trigger it just when I need to use it.  Also I need to edit and make custom which would be altered if the script was on edit. I do love the clearing the open sheet first.

Comment: What error are you having in line 15? Maybe you are trying to run CopyDataToNewFile directly and the script doesn't recognize the variable 'values'? If you just want it to run when you want it you can just change the name of the first function so that it is not an onEdit trigger. Also I don't understand what you mean by "I need to edit and make custom which would be altered if the script was on edit". What is it that you want to edit? And why you cannot to that?

Comment: Ok your script works. And it does what I need. But I do need to put it on a trigger. The reason is we use this open list to give employees choices they can pick from. So I have it set up to save a list offered to diffrent employees. If the list changes on Edit then the master list will change and the saved list will change since they feed off each other. So I need to be able to sort the list only when I need.

Comment: Are you sure you want this in a trigger? It is in a trigger already, an onEdit trigger. Actually, from your words, I understand that you just want your function to run when you make it run manually. So there should not be an onEdit trigger. Also, how is the OPEN tab modifying the MAIN tab? The onEdit checks if the edited cell is from column H in MAIN tab, and if it is not, it does nothing, so an edit in OPEN wouldn't change anything in MAIN.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that the script runs only when you want to. Tell me if that's ok for you.